# Double digits in R

Tags: r, double, character, matching

I have a question about the way R handles double, numeric and character data types internally.

My problem arises from this snippet of code:

```
dn <- 1.0
dc <- "1.0"
dn == dc  #  FALSE
dn  # 1
as.double(dc) # 1
```

The problem is I expected a double to retain the formatting, the digits after the comma, instead of being cut in such a brutal way which makes it difficult to compare it to a character version of the same number.
Of course the problem is not present with numbers like, say 16.2, for which the formatting is correctly retained.

Is there a way to make the 'double' formatting lasting?

Thank you very much

Comment: are you asking about the formatting when outputting numerics? if so, see `?format`.  Or are you asking about machine precision? In which case you want `all.equal(as.numeric(dc) ,dn)`

Comment: ORLY?  What's the difference between `16.2` and `16.20000` ?  But more to the point,  there's no such thing as "the character version" of a number.

Comment: both `sprintf("%.1f", dn) == dc` and `dn == as.double(dc)` are TRUE. You cannot expect to compare a number with a string and hope this will evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: @carloscinelli I expected it to be TRUE simply because 16.2 == "16.2" --> TRUE and so it seemed to me obvious the TRUE in this case too. It seems like R applies an automatic casting to a simpler type before the comparison

Comment: @carlwitthoft if you compare a double and a character there is indeed a difference between 16.2 and 16.20000 if you have a precise format to respect. The character version of a number is simply the string representing the number

Comment: You are missing the point.  You can create any character string you want to "look like" the representation of a number.  It's still not the number,  and the printed representation of a stored `double` is just another character string.  There is no valid way to compare a numerical value with a char string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dn <- 1.0
sprintf("%.1f",dn)
# [1] "1.0"
sprintf("%.2f",dn)
# [1] "1.00"
sprintf("%.22f",dn)
# [1] "1.0000000000000000000000"

dc == sprintf("%.1f",dn)
#[1] TRUE
```

`dn` is stored internally as double precision float ("numeric" in R). How you display it is up to you.

Comment: Ok, my problem was only "1.0" == 1.0 --> FALSE because it seemed like he did an internal conversion casting the double to an integer